# Is it possible to use classic CodeIgniter routes and third_party/MX/Router.php at the same time?

Tags: codeigniter

Is it possible to use classic CodeIgniter routes and third_party/MX/Router.php at the same time?

Let's say I want to use my classical controllers in application/controllers directory togetger with my models.

Is that possible in CodeIgniter + HMVC scenario?

Is there any tutorial how to do that?

Comment: Any idea if it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You just do it; they both work together